# User Creation Form Like iOS Contact Creation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What I am trying to do is create a form that looks and works like the iOS contact creation form does. It looks like custom UITableViewCells with text fields in them but surely thats not all it is.
Also how does the scrolling work? Is it all inside a UIScrollView?
I'm not asking for in depth run throughs but maybe some pointers in the right direction and maybe some links to some tutorials.
Thanks
Disco

Comment: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so the scrolling is automatic. Google around for myriad tutorials on custom `UITableView` implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a UITableView with multiple sections.  You can read [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5841-uitableview-section-dividers-like-ones-iphone-contacts.html) about someone trying to accomplish something similar.  In short, there are default styles that will accomplish most all of what you are looking for.